# Add html element within td after Ajax request in jQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I want to add html element within td after get response from ajax.

Result will be somethings like:

```
<tr>
<td class="mycus-class" data-title="abc"><span class="mycus-class2">XYZ</span></td>
<td class="mycus-class" data-title="ghi"><span class="mycus-class2">GKL</span></td>
.....
</tr>
```

Comment: Far too broad. We don't know if the ajax is bound to the plugin or not. Need to put forth more effort outlining your issues especially when it involves a complex plugin

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Very easy with a [**`render()`**](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html) function, here a little demo :

```
var data = [
    { firstName: 'john', lastName : 'doe' }
]

var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    data : data,
    columns : [
       {  data : 'firstName',
          render : function(data, type, row) {
              return '<span class="mycus-class2">'+data+'</span>'
          }    
       },
       {  data : 'lastName' }
   ]        
})
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/e9be48oq/**

---

You can target multiple columns in one call :

```
columnDefs : [
   { targets : [0,3,4,5],
     render : function(data, type, row) {
        return '<span class="mycus-class2">'+data+'</span>'
     }     
   }
]
```

Comment: @chotesah, consider accepting the answer if it helped you out.

Answer (score 1):

```js
  "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
                console.log(aData[1]);
                if (aData[1] == "Imported")
                {
                    // $('td').css('background-color', '#FBE9E7');
                     $(nRow).find('td:eq(1)').addClass('label label-success');
                } else if (aData[1] == "Inactive") {
                    $(nRow).find('td:eq(1)').addClass('label label-danger');
                } else if(aData[1] == "Exported") {
                   $(nRow).find('td:eq(1)').addClass('label label-primary');
                }else{
                  $(nRow).find('td:eq(1)').html('<span class="label label-default">'+aData[1]+'</span>');
                    // $.addClass('label label-default');
                }

            },
```