# Use local json data inside dataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

The Jquery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var total = [];
  $.ajax({
    url: 'user.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
      // get the `airport` array 
      var device = json.siteList;
      var j = 1;

      // loop through the array to populate your list
      $.each(device, function(i, sites) {
        // console.log(sites.siteName)
        // $('#data_table').append("<tr>" + "<td>" + sites.siteName + "</td>" + "</tr>");
        $.each(sites.deviceList, function(i, values) {
          item = {}
          item['siteName'] = sites.siteName;
          item["deviceName"] = values.deviceName;
          item["count"] = values.count;
          total.push(item);
        });
      });

      console.log(total);
      $('#example').DataTable({
        "aaData": total,
        "aoColumns": [{
            "sTitle": "siteName"
          },
          {
            "sTitle": "deviceName"
          },
          {
            "sTitle": "count"
          },
        ]
      });
    }
  });
});
```

The total variable output comes from user.json file where nested format json data is stored so i first converted it to normal json data and now i want to use it inside dataTable method
The output of total variable is given below:

```
0: {siteName: "Site1", deviceName: "S1device1", count: "1"}
1: {siteName: "Site1", deviceName: "S1device2", count: "2"}
2: {siteName: "Site2", deviceName: "S2device1", count: "1"}
3: {siteName: "Site2", deviceName: "S2device2", count: "2"}
4: {siteName: "Site3", deviceName: "S3device1", count: "1"}
5: {siteName: "Site3", deviceName: "S3device2", count: "2"}
length: 6
```

Facing problem to use it please help me out,
Any help will be highly appreciated ,
Thank you in advance..........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `mData` property along with `sTitle` to define which column should receive which data. Like `"aoColumns": [{"sTitle": "siteName", "mData": "siteName", },...]`.

Your `$('#example').DataTable({...});` code will be like below.

```
$('#example').DataTable({
  "aaData": total,
  "aoColumns": [{
      "sTitle": "siteName",
      "mData": "siteName"
    },
    {
      "sTitle": "deviceName",
      "mData": "deviceName"
    },
    {
      "sTitle": "count",
      "mData": "count"
    },
  ]
});
```

---

To add `checkbox` you can refer [Add html element within td after Ajax request in jQuery DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32993673/add-html-element-within-td-after-ajax-request-in-jquery-datatables).

You should update code like below.

```
$('#example').DataTable({
  "aaData": total,
  "columns": [{
      "data": "siteName",
    },
    {
      "data": "deviceName"
    },
    {
      "data": "count"
    },
    {
      render: function(data, type, row) {
        return '<input type="checkbox" />'
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: hey how can i add check box in it can u help bro please?